# Python Spyne custom output parameters

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I need an output like this in Spyne:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getActiveServicesResponse xmlns="http://mci.tajmi.ir/">
            <getActiveServicesReturn>12345:2030:hafez poem:hafez </getActiveServicesReturn>
            <getActiveServicesReturn>12346:2031:شعر طنز:tanz </getActiveServicesReturn>
            <getActiveServicesReturn>bardari123:203861:سرویس بارداري :bar
</getActiveServicesReturn>
        </getActiveServicesResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I can generate is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://mci.tajmi.ir/">
    <soap11env:Body>
        <tns:getActiveServicesResponse>
            <tns:getActiveServicesReturn>
                <tns:string>12345:2030:hafez poem:hafez</tns:string>
                <tns:string>12346:2031:شعر طنز:tanz </tns:string>
                ....
            </tns:getActiveServicesReturn>
        </tns:getActiveServicesResponse>
    </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

How can I customize the output? I tried complex methods without success.

Comment: Please add your spyne code as well

Answer (score 1):

have a look at my code at https://github.com/timi-ro/simulator. you can find how to make it. Also read it: 
[Spyne - how to duplicate one elements of wsdl file created by spyne?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453596/spyne-how-to-duplicate-one-elements-of-wsdl-file-created-by-spyne)